# Order entries by content of their fields

Tags: entries, order

Can I order entries by the content of a field every entry has?

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('entries').order(  *first time field of a matrix block within the entry*  ).all() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the Matrix table and the Matrix content table in that case to order by this specific field. `LeftJoin` will allow you to only join the first block. If you have several different block ids you need to `leftJoin` only blocks with your block type ID

```
{% set field = craft.app.getFields().getFieldByHandle('yourFieldHandle') %}
{% set entries = craft
    .entries()
    .section('entries')
    .leftJoin('{{%matrixblocks}} matrixblocks', '[[matrixblocks.ownerId]] = [[elements.id]]')
    .leftJoin(
        field.contentTable . ' myContentTable',
        '[[myContentTable.elementId]] = [[matrixblocks.id]]'
     )
    .orderBy({'myContentTable.fieldprefix_fieldHandle': SORT_ASC})
    .all()
%}
```

change `myContentTable.fieldprefix_fieldHandle` to your exact DB column or fetch it dynamically.